# Linux using grep command

Tags: linux, filter, grep

After using grep command, i will give you a small example

> grep test

test this is first line : 1

test this is second line : 2

test this is third line  : 3

test this is fourth line : 4

---

How to filter the last line after grep command executed

finally i need the result 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I don't misunderstand you:

```
$grep test | tail -1
>test this is fourth line : 4

$grep test | tail -1 | awk '{print $7}'
>4
```

`$7` is 'the seventh column' in `awk`.

Comment: I need one more suggestion how to minus the "test this is fourth line :" from that line, i need the final result as 4

Comment: hOw to grep only first line that is "test this is first line : 1"